# What is "Robo-reviewing"?

Tags: support, review-queue

Currently on the review page it says:

> Robo-reviewing plagiarized content.
>
> Come back in 7 days to continue reviewing.

What does this mean? Are posts safe from being voted-to-close for the next 7 days?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It probably means that you have been found to be approving edits containing content copied straight from other sources, most likely Wikipedia, too easy, almost automatically ('robotically').
This often happens on tag descriptions.

You are encouraged to take a break from reviewing and return to it in 7 days. I'm not sure if this goes for all queues or just the edit queue, you'll have to check that yourself.

Meanwhile, please feel free to participate in the rest of the stack.

Comment: That makes sense, there was a string of tag edits over the last few days.

Comment: This makes sense. On Friday of last week, I pointed out in chat that a person (I pointed out someone else, but mods may have also looked into other users' stats) had spent about 4 seconds each reviewing tag wiki/excerpts, and they had all contained plagiarized content.

Comment: I'm curious if this applies to other review responses.  I have a personal policy of skipping review tasks for any canon I'm unfamiliar with, unless the appropriate response is absolutely unambiguous.

Comment: @DarthSatan Skipping should be fine.